# Python 3 script that draws animals using basic functions

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and only started learning a couple months ago. I get that this is a really unsophisticated code and I'm a newbie, but are there any blatant issues with it that I can improve upon? I just kind of threw everything I know together to see if I'm cut out for this kind of thing.

Also I'm a first time poster so I do apologize in advance if something is not said with etiquette.

```
# Attempts to respond to all possible inputs

# This block just asks the user's name
print('Hello!\nMy name is Monty!')
print("\nWhat's your name?")
user_name = input()  # I want to eventually import some sort of 'autocorrect' library if that exists
print(f'\nHi {user_name.title()}!')
print('Nice to meet you.\n')

# This block asks the user's fav color
favorite_color = input('What is your favorite color or colors?\n')
print('\n'+favorite_color[0].upper() + favorite_color[1:].lower(), 'just happens to be my favorite too!')
print('Amazing!\n')

# This block contains lists for later use
yes_list = ['yes', 'Yes', 'y', 'Y', 'yeah', 'Yeah', 'ye', 'Ye', 'yes please', 'yes, please', 'sure', 'Sure',
            'of course', 'of course!', 'definitely', 'Definitely']
no_list = ['no', 'No', 'n', 'N', 'nah', 'Nah', 'nope', 'Nope', 'no thanks',
           'No thanks', 'No, thanks', 'No, thank you', 'no thank you.', 'no, thank you']
dog_list = ['dog', 'Dog', 'the dog', 'The dog', 'doggie', 'Doggie', 'a dog']
cat_list = ['cat', 'Cat', 'the cat', 'The cat', 'kittie', 'Kittie']
mouse_list = ['mouse', 'Mouse', ' the mouse', 'The mouse', 'mousy', 'Mousy']
draw_list = ['draw', 'Draw', 'DRAW', 'please draw', 'Please draw', 'PLEASE DRAW',
             'draw please', 'Draw please', 'DRAW PLEASE', 'draw, please', 'Draw, please']
emptyAnimal_list = []
newEmptyAnimal_list = []
animalsNotViewed_list = []
animalListContents = ['> dog drawing', '> cat drawing', '> mouse drawing']
are_ya_sure = ['No']
separator = ''

# This block asks the user if they want the program to draw
print('I can draw a dog, a cat, or a mouse, ya know!')
print('Do you want me to draw one?')
start = 0
while start == 0:  # Primary while loop
    drawing_decision = input()
    if drawing_decision in dog_list or drawing_decision in cat_list or drawing_decision in mouse_list:  # User must say something in yes or no list first
        print("\nYes or no please! Try again.")
        continue  # Brings to the top of primary while loop
    elif drawing_decision not in dog_list and drawing_decision not in cat_list and drawing_decision not in mouse_list\
            and drawing_decision not in yes_list and drawing_decision not in no_list:  # If user types another animal, it will reject
        print('\nI can only draw a dog, cat, or mouse!')
    if drawing_decision in yes_list:  # If user responds correctly, enter secondary while loop
        animal_selection = 0
        while animal_selection == 0:
            print("\nWhich one do you want me to draw?")
            animal_selection = input()
            if animal_selection in dog_list:  # If user responds dog, print dog
                print('\nHere I go!\nBam:')
                print('''                       ㅤ ／￣￣ヽ＿
        　                /^ヽ ・     ●
                          ｜# ｜　＿＿ノ
                         　`―-)=(    ／￣＼／￣＼
                        　　／ㅤ ) l  |         |
                        　c(　　ﾉ     ＼       ／
                      　  _｣ LL_   　   ＼  ／
        　                (＿＿)_)''')
                print("It's Snoopy!\n")
                print('Do you want me to draw any other one?')
                emptyAnimal_list.append('> dog drawing')  # Append to empty list for later
                other_animals = input()  # Do you want to draw another one?
                if other_animals in yes_list:
                    animal_selection = 0
                elif other_animals in no_list:  # If not, thank them and list drawings viewed
                    if '> dog drawing' in emptyAnimal_list and '> cat drawing' in emptyAnimal_list \
                            and '> mouse drawing' in emptyAnimal_list:
                        print('\nI hope you enjoyed my 3 drawings!')
                        print("They're not the best, but they're the only 3 I can draw, for I am a lowly automaton!")
                        emptyAnimal_list.append('> dog drawing')
                        break
                    else:
                        print('\nI hope you enjoyed my:\n')
                        for x in emptyAnimal_list:
                            if x not in newEmptyAnimal_list:
                                newEmptyAnimal_list.append(x)
                        print('\n'.join(newEmptyAnimal_list))
                        print(f"\nI'm able to draw 3 but at least you saw {len(newEmptyAnimal_list)} of them!")
                        for x in animalListContents:
                            if x not in newEmptyAnimal_list:
                                animalsNotViewed_list.append(x)
                        print("I hope you're able to see my:\n")
                        print('\n'.join(animalsNotViewed_list),'\n')
                        print('Next time!')
                elif other_animals in dog_list or other_animals in cat_list or other_animals in mouse_list:  # If user enters an accepted animal before yes or no, reprimand and continue
                    print("Yes or no next time! But go ahead:")
                    animal_selection = 0
                else:  # If user asks to draw an unaccepted animal
                    animal_selection = 1
                    print('I can only draw a dog, cat, or mouse!')
                    while animal_selection == 1:
                        animal_selection = 0
            elif animal_selection in cat_list:  # If user responds cat, print cat
                print('\nHere I go!\nBam:')
                print('''                    ／＞　 フ
                    | 　_　_| 
                  ／` ミ＿xノ 
                 /　　　　 |
                /　 ヽ　　 ﾉ
                │　　|　|　|
        ／￣|　　 |　|　|
        (￣ヽ＿_ヽ_)__)
        ＼二)''')
                print("Meow\n")
                print('Do you want me to draw any other one?')
                emptyAnimal_list.append('> cat drawing')  # Append to empty list for later
                other_animals = input()  # Do you want to draw another one?
                if other_animals in yes_list:
                    animal_selection = 0
                elif other_animals in no_list:  # If not, thank them and list drawings viewed
                    if '> dog drawing' in emptyAnimal_list and '> cat drawing' in emptyAnimal_list \
                            and '> mouse drawing' in emptyAnimal_list:
                        print('\nI hope you enjoyed my 3 drawings!')
                        print("They're not the best, but they're the only 3 I can draw, for I am a lowly automaton!")
                        emptyAnimal_list.append('> cat drawing')
                        break
                    else:
                        print('\nI hope you enjoyed my:\n')
                        for x in emptyAnimal_list:
                            if x not in newEmptyAnimal_list:
                                newEmptyAnimal_list.append(x)
                        print('\n'.join(newEmptyAnimal_list))
                        print(f"\nI'm able to draw 3 but at least you saw {len(newEmptyAnimal_list)} of them!")
                        for x in animalListContents:
                            if x not in newEmptyAnimal_list:
                                animalsNotViewed_list.append(x)
                        print("I hope you're able to see my:\n")
                        print('\n'.join(animalsNotViewed_list),'\n')
                        print('Next time!')
                elif other_animals in dog_list or other_animals in cat_list or other_animals in mouse_list:  # If user enters an accepted animal before yes or no, reprimand and continue
                    print("Yes or no next time! But go ahead:")
                    animal_selection = 0
                else:  # If user asks to draw an unaccepted animal
                    animal_selection = 1
                    print('I can only draw a dog, cat, or mouse!')
                    while animal_selection == 1:
                        animal_selection = 0
            elif animal_selection in mouse_list:  # If user responds mouse, print mouse
                print('\nHere I go!\nBam:')
                print(r'''                 .-"""-.
                /        \
         .-"""-.-`.-.-.</  _
        /      _,-\ ()()_/:)
        \     / ,  `     `|
         '-..-| \-.,___,  /
               \ `-.__/  /
                `-.__.-'`''')
                print("It's Mickey!\n")
                print('Do you want me to draw any other one?')
                emptyAnimal_list.append('> mouse drawing')  # Append to empty list for later
                other_animals = input()  # Do you want to draw another one?
                if other_animals in yes_list:
                    animal_selection = 0
                elif other_animals in no_list:  # If not, thank them and list drawings viewed
                    if '> dog drawing' in emptyAnimal_list and '> cat drawing' in emptyAnimal_list \
                            and '> mouse drawing' in emptyAnimal_list:
                        print('\nI hope you enjoyed my 3 drawings!')
                        print("They're not the best, but they're the only 3 I can draw, for I am a lowly automaton!")
                        emptyAnimal_list.append('> mouse drawing')
                        break
                    else:
                        print('\nI hope you enjoyed my:\n')
                        for x in emptyAnimal_list:
                            if x not in newEmptyAnimal_list:
                                newEmptyAnimal_list.append(x)
                        print('\n'.join(newEmptyAnimal_list))
                        print(f"\nI'm able to draw 3 but at least you saw {len(newEmptyAnimal_list)} of them!")
                        for x in animalListContents:
                            if x not in newEmptyAnimal_list:
                                animalsNotViewed_list.append(x)
                        print("I hope you're able to see my:\n")
                        print('\n'.join(animalsNotViewed_list),'\n')
                        print('Next time!')
                elif other_animals in dog_list or other_animals in cat_list or other_animals in mouse_list:  # If user enters an accepted animal before yes or no, reprimand and continue
                    print("Yes or no next time! But go ahead:")
                    animal_selection = 0
                else:  # If user asks to draw an unaccepted animal
                    animal_selection = 1
                    print('I can only draw a dog, cat, or mouse!')
                    while animal_selection == 1:
                        animal_selection = 0
            elif animal_selection in no_list:  # If user says no during 'which drawing' question
                print("\nAre you sure you don't want to see any of my drawings?")
                confirmation = 0
                while confirmation == 0:
                    confirmation = input()
                    if confirmation in yes_list:  # Exits this block
                        print(f'\nSorry you feel that way {user_name}!')
                        break
                    elif confirmation in no_list:  # Returns to animal selection
                        print('\nOK!')
                        animal_selection = 0
                        break
                    else:  # Asks exit confirmation question again
                        print("\nI'm not sure I understood. Do you want to leave or not?")
                        confirmation = 0
            else:  # If user asks to draw an unaccepted animal
                animal_selection = 1
                print('I can only draw a dog, cat, or mouse!')
                while animal_selection == 1:
                    animal_selection = 0
        print('\nGreat meeting you', user_name.title() + '!')  # If user says no during additional drawing question
    elif drawing_decision in no_list:  # If user says no during first question regarding drawing
        no_draw = 1
        while no_draw == 1:
            if no_draw == 1:
                are_ya_sure.append('?')
                print(separator.join(are_ya_sure))
                print('\nAll ya gotta do is say "yes."')
            break
        no_draw = 1
```

Comment: *[...] using basic functions*. I don't see even one function, which is the biggest issue. I might write a full review over the weekend.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not familiar with the proper terminology. I would truly appreciate that as I'm looking for anything to help me get better in terms of having a logical mindset when writing programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good go for a beginner, but it could do with a little tidying up.

### Functions

While you may not have learned them yet, functions are essential to working with larger codes and breaking down structures. Here you have called them "blocks", but really they should be functions and written as such. You can write a function as follows:

```
# This block just asks the user's name
print('Hello!\nMy name is Monty!')
print("\nWhat's your name?")
user_name = input()  # I want to eventually import some sort of 'autocorrect' library if that exists
print(f'\nHi {user_name.title()}!')
print('Nice to meet you.\n')
```

becomes

```
def print_introduction() -> str: # We can say what type the function returns
    """
    This function greets the user and asks their name
    Returns: their name
    """
    print('Hello!\nMy name is Monty!')
    user_name = input("What's your name? ")
    print(f'\nHi {user_name.title()}!')
    print('Nice to meet you.\n')
    return user_name.title()
```

The indentetation delimits the function, string at the top (docstring) becomes the help (run this in Python and try `help(print_introduction)`), and this function returns the name in a standard format for later use if we want.

We can call (run) it with:

```
print_introduction() # Discards the returned name
user = print_introduction() # Stores the name in `user`
print(f"Oh! I guess you really are called {user}.")
```

### Simpler Constants

You can simplify a lot of your constants down. Take `yes_list`:

```
yes_list = ['yes', 'Yes', 'y', 'Y', 'yeah', 'Yeah', 'ye', 'Ye', 'yes please', 'yes, please', 'sure', 'Sure',
            'of course', 'of course!', 'definitely', 'Definitely']
```

It has a lot of manual case-insensitivity which you really don't need. You have already used `str.upper()`, `str.lower()` and `str.title()` so you know they exist. We can simplify it down to just:

```
# I have switched this to a tuple here
# Lists are used for things which might change as they are mutable
# Tuples are used for things which won't change as they are fixed. We can't add/remove or change the elements of a tuple
yes_list = ('yes' 'y', 'yeah', 'ye', 'yes please', 'yes, please', 'sure', 'of course', 'of course!', 'definitely')

if some_user_input.lower() in yes_list:
    ...
```

We still have some duplication though. Perhaps we just want to strip all punctuation from user input. Perhaps it's time for another function *with arguments*.

```
def preprocess_input(input_str: str) -> str:
    """
    Removes all punctuation and downcases input_str
    Returns: processed string
    """
    output_str = "".join(letter for letter in input_str if letter.isalpha() or letter.isspace())
    return output_str.lower()

yes_list = ('yes' 'y', 'yeah', 'ye', 'yes please', 'please', 'sure', 'of course', 'definitely')

some_user_input = "y.;eS;."
processed_user_input = preprocess_input(some_user_input)
if processed_user_input in yes_list:
    ...
```

Now we might not want this so flexible, but the beauty of a function is that you can write it once, use it everywhere and if you decide it's not quite right, you only have to change it once!

Say we actually wanted to collapse multiple spaces we just need to add one line to our function (`output_str = " ".join(output_str.split())`) and it's updated everywhere!

### Simpler Logic

You do a lot of setting a variable to `0` and looping until it's not `0` anymore:

```
start = 0
while start == 0:  # Primary while loop
```

Now `start` is never changed in your code. Do you actually want an infinite loop? Make it clear:

```
while True:
```

In other cases where the variable does change, you probably want to use a boolean (`True` or `False`)

```
confirmation = False
while not confirmation:
    ...
```

In most cases you don't need the variable at all and you do seem to know about `break`, so use it with an infinite loop instead.

You have several unnecessary logic blocks:

```
animal_selection = 1
print('I can only draw a dog, cat, or mouse!')
while animal_selection == 1:
    animal_selection = 0
```

This entire block is equivalent to:

```
print('I can only draw a dog, cat, or mouse!')
animal_selection = 0
```

With a lot of extra noise.

```
no_draw = 1
while no_draw == 1:
    if no_draw == 1:
        are_ya_sure.append('?')
        print(separator.join(are_ya_sure))
        print('\nAll ya gotta do is say "yes."')
    break
no_draw = 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
no_draw = 1
are_ya_sure.append('?')
print(separator.join(are_ya_sure))
print('\nAll ya gotta do is say "yes."')
```

As the conditions are always `True`

Note here that `are_ya_sure` doesn't need to be a `list`, you can append to a `str`:

```
x = "Are you sure"
for _ in range(10):
    x += "?"
    print(x)
```

### Building lists

To build lists, we don't really need to have them declared ahead of time. Python has what are called list comprehensions which allow us to write:

```
even_numbers = []
for number in range(10):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even_numbers.append(number)
```

as simply:

```
even_numbers = [number for number in range(10) if number % 2 == 0]
```

In your case, the block:

```
newEmptyAnimal_list = []
for x in emptyAnimal_list:
    if x not in newEmptyAnimal_list:
        newEmptyAnimal_list.append(x)
```

Is trying to construct a `list` with no duplicates. We call this a `set` and we can do this simply as:

```
newEmptyAnimal_list = set(emptyAnimal_list)
```

Note, however, that a `set` is a different type to `list` (just as an `int` is not a `float` even though they both represent numbers), but we can convert it back to a `list` by doing:

```
newEmptyAnimal_list = list(set(emptyAnimal_list))
```

though generally this isn't usually necessary once you're used to using different types.

### Consistency

You have a lot of newlines (`\n`) in various places in your strings; at the front, back, the middle. You also switch between using `'` and `"` to delimit your strings. While not essential, sticking to one thing consistently makes it easier to modify your code in the future and work out why things aren't working.

Your variables are also a mixture of `lowerCamelCase` and `snake_case`. Pick one! [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommends using `UPPER_SNAKE` for (global) constants, `lower_snake` for most other things.

### Summary

I'm not going to write the whole thing for you, but I want to give you a bit of a framework to base the next version on:

```
YES_LIST = ( ... )
NO_LIST = ( ... )
...

def preprocess_input(input_str: str) -> str:
    " As above "
    ...

def get_yes_no(prompt: str) -> bool:
    ...

def get_animal_to_draw() -> int:
    ...

def print_introduction() -> None:
    " As above "
    ...

def draw_cat():
def draw_mouse():
def draw_dog():
    ...

def print_drawn_list_response(drawn_animals: set) -> None:
     " Incomplete "
     print("You've seen my {', '.join(drawn_animals)}. I can still draw ...")

def main():
    drawn_animals = set()

    user = print_introduction()
    while len(drawn_animals) != 3:
        if not drawn_animals: # Empty list/set is `False`
            response = get_yes_no("Would you like me to draw an animal?")
        else:
            response = get_yes_no("Would you like me to draw another?")

        if response:
            to_draw = get_animal_to_draw()
            if to_draw == "mouse":
                draw_mouse()
            elif ...
                ...

            drawn_animals.add(to_draw)
            print_drawn_list_response(drawn_animals)
        else:
            break

    print(f"Great meeting you, {user}!")


# Will be a bit mysterious for now, but good practice to do
# See other questions as to why
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. You have no idea how much I appreciate your time, I will be working on the code with these points in mind and continue to improve. Thank you!